# Connect Normal calls to Asterisk Server

Tags: asterisk, phone, sip

I am trying to develop a phone system just like vitelity. I am using asterisk as backend. Main problem is to connect pstn call to my asterisk server. that is when i dial a number from my phone(including mobiles) it should be connected to my server.

**Can a normal phone call(pstn) can be connected to asterisk server? Does this have any government regulations?**

I am from India and we don't have a good provider like vitelity. Since i am a techie and likes to do something new and different to me, I am trying to develop this. Can any one please help me out to sort this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Asterisk is a PBX. It can manage and route calls coming from one media to another for example, from IP (SIP) to PSTN or viceversa.

First of all you need to have connectivity to PSTN media. To achieve that you will need a hardware adapter to connect to the physical media.

There are hardware cards and VoIP Gateways that can connect to digital connections (T1 / E1) like [these](https://www.digium.com/products/telephony-cards/digital) and [these](https://www.digium.com/products/voip-gateways).

Digium and another vendors also have analog cards to connect to traditional analog lines like [these](https://www.digium.com/products/telephony-cards/analog).

About government regulations, is usual that if you want to **sell** phone services then you have to set up a company and request a license as voice provider. I believe that in your country it is regulated by [*The Telecom Regulatory Authority Of India*](http://www.trai.gov.in/)